# Problems with launching a vue project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, vue.js

I have cloned a project in github, to install the dependencies, I wrote `npm ci`, but there are some problems with installation. Here is the screenshot of the errors:

[image: Errors screenshot]
[image: Errors screenshot 2]

I have tried to use `npm cache clear --force` as was suggested to do in similar questions. Also I installed Visual Studio + Desktop development with C++, upgraded python. The same problem occurs when I try to use `npm install`. Could you please help to solve the problem?

```
5523 verbose stack Error: command failed
5523 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
5523 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
5523 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
5523 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
5524 verbose pkgid deasync@0.1.20
5525 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ideapad L340\Desktop\frontend\frontend
5526 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
5527 verbose node v16.13.1
5528 verbose npm  v8.7.0
5529 error code 1
5530 error path C:\Users\Ideapad L340\Desktop\frontend\frontend\node_modules\deasync
5531 error command failed
5532 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
5533 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
5533 error gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
5533 error gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
5533 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS 
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS "D:\VisualStudio"
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.3.32819.101) found at:
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS "D:\VisualStudio"
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS - not found
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS 
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
5533 error gyp ERR! find VS 
5533 error gyp ERR! configure error 
5533 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ideapad L340\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
5533 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
5533 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
5533 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ideapad L340\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
5533 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ideapad L340\Desktop\frontend\frontend\node_modules\deasync
5533 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
5533 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
5533 error gyp ERR! not ok 
5533 error Build failed
5534 verbose exit 1
5535 timing npm Completed in 113499ms
5536 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1661634332889
5537 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1661634390048
5538 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1661634390053
5539 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1661634390054
5540 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1661634390346
5541 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/deasync 1661634390346
5542 verbose code 1
```

Comment: Do you know what version of node this project was built to work with? If yes, check if you've the same version. This could possibly be because you've a different version of node than the one required by the project. I once had to bang my head against the wall for days because of this.

Comment: Is Visual Studio an IDE people actually use to do frontend Vue development? I think maybe OP meant to download "Visual Studio Code" which is a completely different program.

Comment: Actually for this reason I have downloaded Visual Studio Code and launched a project from a terminal in VS Code, but anyway  this problem occurs @yoduh

Comment: Finally I have downloaded and set up Visual Studio, but nevertheless the other issues appeared. If you mind, I can send you the screenshots

Comment: @NafisaValieva Is the project you're trying to build your own team project or some publicly available repository? If it's a something publicly available, could you share the URL to it? Also, did you check the node version required by the project?